# how to get current time using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

lets say for example, I have ten nodes with a name and time property. i have used the timestamp() function but it returns a value, that is the difference between the current time and the 1st of january, 1970 in milliseconds. What i want to know is, is there a function or possiblitiy to get the current time. if its there, can i get a sample code on how we can use it as an attribute in a node. also do tell me if its possible to extract data from the node that was updated a few hours ago using timestamp function itself

Answer (score 21):

Updated for 2018:
There are now date types in Neo4j. You can use real date functions, and have them be range-lookup-friendly index-backed. :)

```
CREATE (:Node{dt:datetime()});

CREATE INDEX ON :Node(dt);

MATCH (n:Node)
WHERE n.dt > datetime('2018-06-24T12:50:35.556+0100')
RETURN n;
```

Updated for 2017 (thanks for comments):
`timestamp()` returns a value for milliseconds. You can do subtraction with this, and calculate the number of milliseconds for "a few hours ago" to see if it is in range.

```
CREATE ({ts:timestamp});

MATCH (n)
WHERE n.ts > timestamp() - (1000*60*60*4) // 4 hours ago
RETURN n;
```

Comment: **UPDATE** We now support numeric range indexes, so it's possible to now make this query super fast.  Also, check out APOC date/time functions: https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_date_time_support